# How to use `cal` to run scripts?

Tags: bash, shell-script

I wrote a script and need to make it run with the `cal` command.
How do I do this?

This is my `.bashrc`:

```
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/bin/X11:/lib/ast/bin:/home/$USER/bin:.
```

Comment: The `cal` command makes a text-mode calender.  Did you mean the `cron` command?

Comment: Oh my god! I think you might be on to something!

Comment: Do you mean you wish to override the default behaviour of `cal`? Instead of showing a calendar, it should run your custom command?

Answer (score 1):

To override the system command `cal` and, instead, run your command which is located in `/home/$USER/bin/cal`, add the following `alias` line to your `~/.bashrc` file:

```
alias cal=/home/$USER/bin/cal
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/bin/X11:/lib/ast/bin:/home/$USER/bin:.
```

By default, an `alias` is only active for interactive sessions.  This means that the above has the advantage that it will *not* be active in shell scripts and, consequently, will not interfere with any such script that depends on `cal` being the usual system `cal`.

Comment: I think your answer makes more sense.